# Defining React-Redux dispatch as generic function property throws error with typescript 3.1.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to upgrade my typescript dependency (2.5.x > 3.1.3) in my React-Redux project. Sadly not without problems :P

I have a base selectpicker React component that expects a function property with a parameter of type IdNameObject:

```
onToggleItem: (item: IdNameObject) => void;
```

The actual function that gets injected into the function prop, is a Redux dispatch function with a parameter of an interface that extends the IdNameObject:

```
updateSelectedLocation: (location: Location) => void;
interface Location extends IdNameObject {...}
```

Typescript now throws an error saying that type Location is not equal to type IdNameObject, obviously.

I tried converting the function property to make it generic:

```
onToggleItem: <T extends IdNameObject>(item: T) => void
```

This however still throws a typescript error:

```
type '(location: Location) => void' is not assignable to type '<T extends IdNameObject>(item: T) => void'
```

Any idea what I should be doing in this case?

---

**Full example case**

I left out all the extra code that is not really needed for this case.

On one side I have a navigation.tsx:

```
interface Location extends IdNameObject {...}

interface Props {
    updateSelectedLocation: (location: Location) => void;
}

class Navigation extends React.Component<Props> {
    public render(): any {
        const {updateSelectedLocation} = this.props;
        return <Selectpicker onToggleItem={updateSelectedLocation}/>;
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: DispatchType) {
    return {
        updateSelectedLocation: (location: Location) => {
            dispatch(updateSelectedLocation(location));
        },
    }
}

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)((Navigation as any));
```

On the other side i have a selectpicker.tsx:

interface Location extends IdNameObject {...}

```
interface Props {
    onToggleItem: (item: IdNameObject) => void;
}

export class Selectpicker extends React.Component<Props> {
    public render(): any {
        const {onToggleItem} = this.props;
        return <Dropdown contentOnToggleItem={onToggleItem}/>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining the type parameter `T` on `onToggleItem`, you've said that every caller of the selectpicker component has to provide an `onToggleItem` implementation that works for every `T`.  What I think you want is that the caller of the selectpicker component chooses the type `T` of the objects being selected when constructing the selectpicker and then provides an `onToggleItem` implementation that works for that specific `T`.  To do that, `T` should be defined on the selectpicker component and on the props interface that contains `onToggleItem` (if you're using one), not on `onToggleItem` itself.

If you're having trouble making this work, please add more of your code (at a minimum, the declaration of the selectpicker class) to the question.

### Update

Based on the example code, here is how you would add `T` to `selectpicker.tsx`:

```
interface Props<T extends IdNameObject> {
    onToggleItem: (item: T) => void;
}

export class Selectpicker<T extends IdNameObject> extends React.Component<Props<T>> {
    public render(): any {
        const {onToggleItem} = this.props;
        return <Dropdown contentOnToggleItem={onToggleItem}/>;
    }
}
```

Then, in `navigation.tsx`, TypeScript should infer that your `<Selectpicker ... />` element is using `T = Location`.  You can also explicitly specify `<Selectpicker<Location> ... />`.

Comment: Thanks @MattMcCutchen! I think I understand what you mean, but am having trouble implementing it. I updated my first post with a bigger code example.

Comment: thanks a lot! Worked through everything :) The only problem I ended up with was in an underlying redux connect function.

`export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps<any>>(mapStateToProps)((MultiColumnDropdown as any));`

OwnProps needed to get the <T extends IdNameObject>, but I could not find a correct place to put that, therefore the any type. This seems to not have any effect on the typings in the MultiColumnDropdown class itself.